# GDP in equilibrium

Tags: macroeconomics, general-equilibrium, demand

I have to find the GDP in equilibrium for a IS LM model. It is given that

$M^d (Y,r)=M_0+M_1Y-M_2r$ and $M^d=M/P$, $M_0,M_1,M_2>0$ and $M^d$ is money demand.

**my solution so far**

I have found that $IS=\frac{1}{1-b}(a-bT+I_0-I_1r+G)$ and $a,b,c,I_0,I_1>0$, $0<b<1$ from an previous result. Then i proceeded to find  $LM=-\frac{M_0}{M_1}+\frac{M}{M_1P}+\frac{M_2r}{M_1}$ (we have to have $Y$ as a function of $r$ and not the usual reversed way). $G,P,M,P$ are all exo.

Now, I do not know how the GDP is derived from equilibrium when we have to express in terms of $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there were no mistakes in IS and LM calculation you just solve one for $r$ substitute into another and solve for output - this is no different then solving a system of two equations.

$$Y = -\frac{M_0}{M_1}+\frac{M}{M_1P}+\frac{M_2r}{M_1} \implies r = \frac{M_1}{M_2}\left( Y +\frac{M_0}{M_1}-\frac{M}{M_1P}\right)$$

just plug this expression for $r$ into the IS and you get the solution.

$$Y = \frac{1}{1-b}(a-bT+I_0-I_1 \frac{M_1}{M_2}\left( Y +\frac{M_0}{M_1}-\frac{M}{M_1P}\right)+G) $$

$$Y^*  = \frac{(1-b)M_2}{((1-b)M_2+ I_1)M_1}   \frac{1}{1-b}(a-bT+I_0 -I_1 \frac{M_1}{M_2}\left(\frac{M_0}{M_1}-\frac{M}{M_1P}\right)+G)\\
=\frac{M_2}{((1-b)M_2+ I_1)M_1} (a-bT+I_0 - \frac{I_1}{M_2}\left( M_0-\frac{M}{P}\right)+G)$$

Comment: Yes  this was my idea as well. I must say the equation looks kind of strange and I will have to double check my calculations for IS and LM. For LM I just had that $M_0+M_1Y-M_2r=M/P$ which is just subtracting everything else than $M_1Y$ and then dividing through by  $M_1$. For IS I have that  $C=a+b(Y-T) \;\; \wedge \;\; I(r)=I_0-I_1 r$ and that $Y=C+I+G$. Substituting thoes into $Y$ yields (I think) the above written IS.

Comment: @bymathformath you can double check the IS and LM but it does not seem anything out of ordinary - see for example, Blanchard et al Macroeconomics where they also get large expression - here expression is complicated mainly by having all those multiple $M$ aggregates instead of just having one $M$. In any case in the textbook you will see that this is how you solve these sort of problems.  Also, if you think the above solved your issue consider accepting it

Comment: Okay great! If you notice any mistake in my comment above regarding the curves please let me know. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @bymathformath I don’t see any glaring mistakes but I also did not went through the calculations

Comment: Okay I see. May I ask why the derivative $dY/dG$ is lower in the equilibrium than the multiplier that is bigger than 1 (the multiplier is $1/(1-C_1)$ where C_1 is between 0 and 1)? Not the mathematics but the economical intepretation

Comment: @bymathformath in short, because in the full model multiplier also depends on the investment spending (this also happens in some goods market equilibrium models if you assume I(Y)) and in addition some of the effect (real) government spending would have would be offset by increase in money supply (and its further effects on price level etc) since in the model above when output increases people’s demand for money increases as well.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand - even though I only wish a short and not too detailed explanation. Because the multiplier depends on investment spending and government spending would increase peoples demand for money would increase and thus the rate of change is lower in the equilibrium than the multiplier that is bigger than 1? I am not getting it

Comment: @bymathformath you can think about it like this. When it comes to investment you see from IS curve that G increases Y but from LM curve you see that if Y increases r increases as well, but then when you go back to IS curve increase in r also decreases Y so G both increases Y directly and decreases is indirectly through r (which is multiplied by investment because investment depends or r) if you look just at IS you ignore this indirect effect Y has on r and investment which lowers the multiplier. Similarly there is a similar effect that works for money supply.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Eventough, I think I might have a problme since I cant show that $dY^* / dG \leq 1$ with this expression.

Comment: Do you agree with that with this current setup this is definetly not surely less than 1

Comment: @bymathformath what do you mean? It can be less than 1 or more than one. If b=0.9,M2=10, I=1 and M1=1 multiplier will be 5 if b=0.9,M2=1,I=1, M1=1 multiplier will be approximately 0.91 so clearly it can be either higher than 1 or less than 1 depending on parameters

Comment: Yes but my assignment problem specify that I have to show that $dY/dG$ is now less than it was before (before I had to show it was bigger than 1) and thus have to show it is equal to or less than 1.

Comment: @bymathformath I don’t know details of your assignment there might be other assumptions about parameter values there

Comment: Every parameter is bigger than 0 except b which is between 0 and 1 i.e $0<b<1$. Should be written in the post.

Comment: and thus the derivative is $dY/dG=\frac{M_2}{M_1(I_1 + M_2 - b M_2)}$ which as you said can be either one of the spectrum ..